# How to pass a class variable into another class variable as array?

Tags: php, arrays, methods

I would like to pass one variable into an array.  I have two classes.  One `MenuClass` is used to register menus - and I need the variable populated as an array. I will be using the second class extended, and passing in multiple menus.  So I need each run to insert another item into the `Main->loaded_menus[`] array.

They are loaded in different files, but loaded at the same time.  Here is a very basic example of what I am working with...

```
class Main {

    public $loaded_Menus = array();

    public function __construct() {}

}

class MenuClass {

    public $name;
    public $id;

    public function build($id, $name) {

        $this->id = $id;
        $this-name = $name;

        $populate = new Main;
        $populate->loaded_Menus[$this->id] = $this->id;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your example which one is extended?

Comment: MenuClass would be the one that is extendable.  The Main class is used as the primary plugin class.

Comment: @Javad please don't edit the OP to answer the question. Point out the "fix" in your answer instead.

Comment: My answer is below, and I mean the below answer not the edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you extend from another class all public properties will be inherited, therefore you don't need to create a new instance of the parent class

```
class MenuClass extends Main {

   public $name;
   public $id;

   public function build($id, $name) {

     $this->id = $id;
     $this-name = $name;

     $this->loaded_Menus[$this->id] = $this->id;
   }
}
```

If you want to keep all previous values in your parent class then define it as static; so while your page is alive the values will be kept

```
class Main {

   public static $loaded_Menus = array();
   public function __construct() {}

}

class MenuClass extends Main {

  public $name;
  public $id;

  public function build($id, $name) {

     $this->id = $id;
     $this-name = $name;

     parent::$loaded_Menus[$this->id] = $this->id;
  }
}
```